# Call to a member function count() on null when loading Gallery

Tags: layout, xml, local.xml, gallery

Im using Amastys Gallery plugin to implement into a tab on the product page, however the above error has come up when I pasted the code into my custom template.

I have called my tab in the local.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="catalog.product.gallery" template="catalog/product/view/gallery.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Gallery</value></action>
</block>
```

And the below code is within my gallery page:

```
<?php
/**
* @author Amasty Team
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2017 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
* @package Mageplace_Gallery
*/

/**
* @var Mageplace_Gallery_Block_Photo_List_Product $this
*/

$_curAlbum        = $this->getCurrentAlbum();
$_photoCollection = $this->getPhotos();
$_photoCount      = $_photoCollection->count();
$_helper          = $this->helper('mpgallery');
$_urlHelper       = $this->helper('mpgallery/url');
$_mode            = $this->getMode();
?>

<div class="box-collateral box-gallery-photos box-up-sell" id="gallery-product-photos">

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top'); ?>

<h2><?php echo $this->__('Related Photos'); ?></h2>

<?php if ($this->getDisplayButtonArea() && $this->isTopButtonsPosition()) : ?>
    <div class="buttons top-buttons">
        <?php if ($this->getDisplayButtons()) : ?>
            <div class="nav-buttons">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Prev'); ?>"
                        <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>onclick="location.href = '<?php echo $this->getPreviousPageUrl(); ?>'"<?php endif; ?>
                        class="button<?php if ($this->isFirstPage()): ?> disabled<?php endif; ?>">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Prev'); ?></span></span>
                </button>

                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next'); ?>"
                        <?php if (!$this->isLastPage()): ?>onclick="location.href = '<?php echo $this->getNextPageUrl(); ?>'"<?php endif; ?>
                        class="button<?php if ($this->isLastPage()): ?> disabled<?php endif; ?>">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Next'); ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->getDisplayUploadButton()) : ?>
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Upload Photo'); ?>"
                        onclick="location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUploadUrl(); ?>'"
                        class="button">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Upload Photo'); ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_photoCount): ?>
    <table class="photos-grid products-grid" id="gallery-photos-product-table">
        <tr>
            <?php $i = 0; ?>
            <?php /** @var Mageplace_Gallery_Model_Photo $_photo */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_photoCollection as $_photo): ?>
                <?php $_photoNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_photo->getName(), null, true); ?>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_urlHelper->getPhotoUrl($_photo); ?>"
                       title="<?php echo $_photoNameStripped; ?>"
                       id="photo-product-image-<?php echo $_photo->getUrlKey(); ?>"
                       class="photo-image product-image">
                        <img
                                src="<?php echo $this->getImage($_photo, 'small_image', $this->getPhotoSize()); ?>"
                                alt="<?php echo $_photoNameStripped; ?>"/>
                    </a>

                    <?php if ($this->getDisplayName()) : ?>
                        <h3 class="photo-name product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_urlHelper->getPhotoUrl($_photo); ?>"
                               title="<?php echo $_photoNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_photo->getName(); ?></a>
                        </h3>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="ratings">
                        <div class="rating-box">
                            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getPhotoAvgRate($_photo); ?>%"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php if ($this->getDisplayUpdateDate()) : ?>
                        <div class="update-date">
                            <?php echo $this->formatDate($_photo->getUpdateDate(), Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($this->getDisplayShortDescription()) : ?>
                        <div class="desc std">
                            <?php echo $_photo->getShortDescription(); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($this->getDisplayShowLink()) : ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_urlHelper->getPhotoUrl($_photo); ?>"
                                       title="<?php echo $_photoNameStripped; ?>"
                                       class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Show'); ?></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('gallery-photos-product-table')</script>
<?php else: ?>
    <div
            class="gallery-photos-product-empty"><?php echo $this->__('There are no product photos to display.'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($this->getDisplayButtonArea() && $this->isBottomButtonsPosition()) : ?>
    <div class="buttons bottom-buttons">
        <?php if ($this->getDisplayButtons()) : ?>
            <div class="nav-buttons">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Prev'); ?>"
                        <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>onclick="location.href = '<?php echo $this->getPreviousPageUrl(); ?>'"<?php endif; ?>
                        class="button<?php if ($this->isFirstPage()): ?> disabled<?php endif; ?>">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Prev'); ?></span></span>
                </button>

                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next'); ?>"
                        <?php if (!$this->isLastPage()): ?>onclick="location.href = '<?php echo $this->getNextPageUrl(); ?>'"<?php endif; ?>
                        class="button<?php if ($this->isLastPage()): ?> disabled<?php endif; ?>">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Next'); ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->getDisplayUploadButton()) : ?>
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Upload Photo'); ?>"
                        onclick="location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUploadUrl(); ?>'"
                        class="button">
                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Upload Photo'); ?></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bottom'); ?>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if (!$this->isJqueryEnable()) : ?>

<?php if ($this->getScrollToPhotos()) : ?>
Event.observe(window, 'load', function () {
    $('gallery-product-photos').scrollTo();
});
<?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    <?php if ($this->getScrollToPhotos()) : ?>
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#gallery-product-photos').offset().top
    }, 0);
    <?php endif; ?>

    $('#gallery-product-photos .photo-image').bind('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var position = 0;
        var imgKey = this.id.replace('photo-product-image-', '');
        for (var i = 0; i < carouselImageUrls.length; i++) {
            if (carouselImageUrls[i]['id'] == imgKey) {
                position = ++i;
                break;
            }
        }

        Lightview.show(carouselImageUrls, {
            controls: {
                slider: {
                    items: <?php echo $this->getLimit() < $_photoCount ? $this->getLimit() : $_photoCount; ?>
                }
            },
            slideshow: <?php echo $this->slideshowDelay(); ?>,
            onShow: function () {
                <?php if($this->isSlideshowAutostart()): ?>
                setTimeout(function () {
                    Lightview.play();
                }, <?php echo $this->slideshowDelay(); ?>);
                <?php endif; ?>
            }
        }, position);
    });

    $('#photo_view_image').css({"cursor": "pointer"});
});

var carouselImageUrls = <?php echo $this->getImagesJson(); ?>;

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is being pulled in fine when I use the below on the view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try this: `$_photoCount = count($_photoCollection);`

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for this. It appears its an issue with the album not even displaying, so going to look further into this and close this question.